# How to Implement Segment.io via GTM for Android/iOS?

Tags: android, ios, google-tag-manager, function-call

I am trying to implement Segment on our apps (both Android and iOS) via GTM containers for both OS.

However, since I m not a app developer I m struggling to understand how to use the function call in GTM, picture below
[image: gtm function call for Android]

Given that this is the code to add an Android app as source for Segment, does anyone know how to proceed in the Tag configuration:
Step 1. Add the Analytics dependency to your build.gradle
The recommended way to install the library for Android is with a build system like Gradle. This makes it dead simple to upgrade versions and add integrations. The library is distributed via wwww Maven Central. Simply add the analytics module to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.+'
}
```

Need more info? Read the complete Android documentation.

Step 2. Initialize the Client
We recommend initializing the client in your Application subclass.

```
// Create an analytics client with the given context and Segment write key.
Analytics analytics = new Analytics.Builder(context, "0Et0DSpva5mxEGNCr7W0vEjiprAWFvTm")
  // Enable this to record certain application events automatically!
  .trackApplicationLifecycleEvents()
  // Enable this to record screen views automatically!
  .recordScreenViews()
  .build();

// Set the initialized instance as a globally accessible instance.
Analytics.setSingletonInstance(analytics);
```

Automatically tracking lifecycle events (Application Opened, Application Installed, Application Updated) is optional, but highly recommended to hit the ground running with core events!

This only installs the Segment integration. This means that all your data will be sent server side to tools. If you need to bundle additional integrations client side, you’ll need to take some additional steps.

Step 3. Add Permissions to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!-- Required for internet. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not deploy an SDK via GTM.

Have your app devs following Segment's guide here: https://segment.com/docs/connections/sources/catalog/libraries/mobile/ios/quickstart/